# Connecting Google Analytics , Google Cloud Platform using JDBC Driver from CData

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-analytics, cdata

that's my first post ever so i'm sorry if i won't be satysfing and if is not in the right place.
Here is my problem:
I have just created a google cloud platform account and a google analytics account.
I did create an account service and an OAuth2.0 client in GCP, and also i enabled the api related to google analytics. What i am trying to do basically is using a jdbc driver to extract my datas from gcp in java. But i've noticed that there is a token which is necessary for OAuth2.0 but is not a jwt token, it justs asks you to login and it will give you the token in the url as a code. Here is the problem, this code has a limited time (1 hour) after that time it will be expired and i should keep calling back again and again the same api
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Within the body the key refresh_token to refresh it
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYe3.png)
else as visible from the image 1 it would give me invalid grant bad request.
Is there any other way to maybe extend the expiration date of that code? I've read all the documentation i could possibly find but i am still missing something.
I've also tried to generate a jwt token using the Json data downloaded from my service account, but after that i tried
the
[JDBC Data connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8KtD.png)
Jdbc data connector and i really didn't understand where to put my datas after that, i could understand OAuth client id
OAuth client secret
Access token
and Refresh token
but i really don't understand which more i should be using, can someone give me a suggest i would appreciate.
PS: I can't use bigquery

Basically i created service and OAuth account,
i enstablished a connection creating a link myown with the datas retrieved from those accounts
and used postman to obtain an access token.
Then i tried to use cdata jdbc

Answer (score 0):

For the Authentication problem you can follow these steps:

- Open your https://console.cloud.google.com and log in to your project, then go to **Credentials**
- Go to  **Service Accounts** and try to Create a service account by clicking on **CREATE CREDENTIALS**
  Insert only a name (whatsoever) and the ID will be auto generated. Leave description empty.
- Click "**CREATE AND CONTINUE**"
  [image: photo1]
- Set "**Owner**" as "Role".
  [image: photo2]
- Click "CONTINUE" and Leave fields empty and click "**DONE**".

Back in the "**Service Accounts**" , you will see an Email has been created, go to the "**Actions**" column and click on the pen icon where you can see "**Edit service account**" and try to edit:

- Go to the "**KEY**" tab and click on "**ADD KEY**" --> "**CREATE NEW KEY**"

[image: photo3]

- Select "**JSON**" and click "**CREATE**". The key is now created and the json should be automatically downloaded. You can save it somewhere that you have the access while initialising the API.